# System UI stopped working, registered receiver both in code and manifest

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Here is a filter of my code:

Sender:

```
public static String ACTION = "some_broadcast";
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //Creating an Intent to be sent through a broadcast
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
                intent.putExtra("something", 1);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }  
    }); 
  }
}
```

On the receiver side (as it is one of the systemui classes, I can only add lines to the existing code and not really changes its structure):

```
public class PhoneStatusBarPolicy {
  ...
  private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (action.equals("some_broadcast")) {
         update(intent);
      }
      else if ...   
   }
  };

  public PhoneStatusBarPolicy(Context context) {
    ...
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("some_broadcast");
    context.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
    ...
  }

  private final void update (Intent intent) {
    //Does something
  }

  ...
}
```

Even though I read that once I registered the receiver, there is no need to add it to the manifest, I’ve added it anyways to he systemui’s `AndroidManifest.xml` because it never reached it:

```
<receiver
   android:name="com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarPolicy"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
         <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="some_broadcast" />
          </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

After running the app on the emulator, the function ‘update’ is being called and does what it should, but I received ‘Unfortunately system UI has stopped”

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to register the receiver twice. It may be the reason for stopping the UI. You can use the below code. It works for me.

Your manifest file and sender seems ok. I'll put the code for the receiver.

```
 public class PhoneStatusBarPolicy extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              String action = intent.getAction();
              if (action.equals("some_broadcast")) {
                 update(intent);
              }
              else if ...   
           }
          };



      private final void update (Intent intent) {
        //Does something
      }

      ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanx! I guess registering twice did cause the problem. However, adding "extends BroadcastReceiver" to a SystemUI class won't affect in other places it shouldn't? I imagine there is a reason why it was written without it till now...